ClickOnce executable build failure
I am using Visual Studio 2022 and publishing a ClickOnce deployment.
Visual Studio is all up to date. The project is x86 architecture with 2 interop dlls.
The deployment publishes with no issues, and it does deploy and install as expected.
The issue is that the executable must be corrupt at the interop level. My understanding is that when you build the project with the setting Embed Interop Types to true on an interop dll, those dlls will be embedded in the executable. When I run the executable, it fails or crashes at the interop logic. I ran WinDbg, I can see it is trying to access that logic and ends up throwing "Security check failure or stack buffer overrun - code c0000409", which could be an overrun in the logic, or maybe could be corrupted data in the stack. If I run it in Visual Studio as a release it performs correctly. If I compare the deployed with the release one is bigger (go figure). That makes me think that the deployment does no build correctly when I publish.
I have tried not to include the manifest, also changing the Embed Interop Type to false, which those dlls are included in the deployment. I have tried other suggestions from the internet. I am stuck!!! **Any help would be appreciated ... **
